# Get String From Different Values Folder in Android

Tags: android, localization

I wanna develop android application for different types of languages. So I have used localization for it. For that I have created different values folder like values-fr, values-ja , values-de. N also created strings.xml with static value according to that values folder. So All is good. But now my question is that I wanna change UI text according to user's selection of language. So How can I manually get particular string values from values->string.xml  for particular language???

I think it may be easy, But I have no idea.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
Locale locale = new Locale("cn");
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale; 
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Yea!! I waited to complete time limit for it :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to get the String from the file like this way

```
String string = getString(R.string.hello);
```

Android will choose the folder based on the mobile locale. See this link for further information about Android localization.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

And this one for String resources if you still have some doubts on how to acces the strings.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

Hope it helps, good luck! :)

Comment: I know dude!! But I want to change mobile locale manually that I got from above answer. Thanks!

Comment: @Jai well then, the main point it´s solving the problem so glad you did it :)